# PHP (Laravel) issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am receiving an error from running the below code?

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value
```

Code:

```
public function setServiceSetting(Request $request) {
    if (!$request->has('setting_key') ||
        !$request->has('setting_value')) {
        return $this->getScriptingResponse();
    }

    $settingKey = $request->input('setting_key');
    $settingValue = $request->input('setting_value');

    $settings = WebsiteSettings::first();

    if ($settings == null) {
        return;
    }

    $setting->$settingKey = $settingValue;
    $settings->save();
}
```

Error Line:

```
$setting->$settingKey = $settingValue;
```

I know the column exists, below anyone suggests that. I also know both parameters are non-null.

Comment: That's a typo man it should be `$settings->$settingKey = $settingValue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is incorrect

```
$settings->$settingKey = $settingValue;
```

try this:

```
$settings->settingKey = $settingValue;
```